# Convert number to list

Tags: string-manipulation

`FromDigits` will convert a list to a number, i.e.

```
FromDigits[{5, 1, 2, 8}]
> 5128
```

Now, I want to convert `5128` back to a list, e.g `{5,1,2,8}`

How do I do that (particularly with a 5000 character long integer)?

Comment: Always have a look at the "See Also" section in the footer of the documenation of a built-in symbol. In this case, `IntegegerDigits` is the first entry in that section.

Comment: Sorry, "FromDigits is effectively the inverse of IntegerDigits and IntegerString." is literally the first line in Details section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `IntegerDigits` do the job

`IntegerDigits[5128]`

`{5, 1, 2, 8}`

However I really wonder how you could do that without defined function. Any idea?